# WebSocket connection to 'ws://<ip>..failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 502

Tags: nginx, websocket, socket.io, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm using node,socket.io,nginx for socket connections for a http based simple application. below is my nginx.conf where i configured the websockets, my socket io is present in socket/socket.io. Strange thing is that the same config works perfectly when I run the node application in localhost and nginx with port 80. Not sure why it is failing in linux which real IP addresses.

```
http {
  upstream io_nodes {
    ip_hash;
    server IP:PORT; --> My application's IP and port
    server IP:PORT;

  }

  include mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  sendfile on;
  keepalive_timeout 1000;

  # HTTP Server
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name IP;
    server_tokens off;
    #proxy_ssl_verify off;

    # prevents 502 bad gateway error
    large_client_header_buffers 8 32k;

    location /dummy/ {
      root html;
      index dummy/index.html;
    }

    location /socket/socket.io {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

      # prevents 502 bad gateway error
        proxy_buffers 8 32k;
        proxy_buffer_size 64k;

      proxy_pass http://io_nodes/;
      proxy_redirect off;

      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    #location /socket.io/ {
    #  proxy_pass http://io_nodes/socket.io/;
    #}

    location /assistlog/socket.io {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    # prevents 502 bad gateway error
        proxy_buffers 8 32k;
        proxy_buffer_size 64k;

      proxy_pass http://10.73.52.187:4444/;
      proxy_redirect off;

      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;

    }
}
}
```

and this is the console error in chrome

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://IP/socket/socket.io/?pathName=%2FDEMOUI%2Findex.html&EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 502
```

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: What about the Nginx logs?

Comment: I have fixed the issue: 
First check whether your browser is supporting the websockets are not by using:

Comment: Please post that as an answer instead of comment

Answer (score 0):

Check list:
First check whether your browser is supporting web sockets using https://websocket.org/echo.html

Then, if you are under organisation proxy, then you need to by pass proxy for local addresses.

Let us say, your organisation proxy IP is some x.x.x.x. You need to by pass some addresses(from the application where you need wss/ws connecctions) to NOT to use your org proxy.

Example in Mac, Chrome: Settings, search for proxy, and there you can see "bypass proxy settings for these hosts&domains". Add your application IP there